# Dosbox USB print Windows 8.1 64Bit

Tags: windows-8.1

Worked fine until I've upgraded to Windows 8.1.

What I did was set the USB printer to `lpt1:` on the local Windows 8 computer and another XP computer via LAN to `lpt2:`, the same way with the same printer on the Windows 8 computer. But now it doesn't work anymore from the Windows 8 machine (where the printer is plugged via USB). Tried already deleting `lpt2:` on the XP one, as well as `lpt1:` on the Windows 8, reset it. Not working... :-( I tried also

```
net use lpt1: \\server\printer password "\user:XXX" /persistent:yes
```

Of course, with the correct server and shared printer name as well as

```
net use \\server\printer "\user:XXX" password /persistent:yes
```

This is the name displayed as a user now. But in C:\users it is named Benutzer1. Tried this one also. Nothing worked. What could be the problem here?

What's strange is that when I type `net use lpt1:` on the XP, I get another error (`67 - The network name wasn't found`) than trying something I didn't set up like lpt2 (`2 - The system can't find the file`). Could this be a possible problem as even if deleted something is left blocking on the Windows 8 computer?

Comment: Windows 8.1 still works without "Live ID". You just need to choose "Create new account" and then (in the form) you have a skip-option at the bottom of the screen. (something like "Sign in without a Microsoft account", can't remember exactly). See also [here](http://www.infobyte.hr/blog/337/windows-8-1-preview-how-to-install-without-microsoft-account-skip-microsoft-account/). It still works for the 'final' version.

Comment: You need to do a `net view` to see all the visible computers. It is probably `Benutzer1` because that is visible after `C:\User`. It it is in `net view` you need to do `net view \\Benutzer1` to see the shared printers. If the printer is visible you can do `net use lpt1 \\Benutzer1\printer_name`. For Windows 8 itself this should work. For Windows XP you could have a problem with the usernames and password but first get it working locally.

Comment: Do you _actually_ mean [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), or do you just mean the "regular" command-line interface? I'm certainly guessing the latter, but please clarify.

Comment: Just to clarify: For the username, you know you need to type `/user:"xxx"`, with the quotes ONLY around the username?

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try: [vDos](http://www.schaars.nl/vDos.7z)

Unzip it to a folder and start the vDos executable.

It should start the DataPerfect 2.3 TestDrive demo program.
Play with it, print and quit.

Modify the autoexec.txt file to start your program.

FYI: vDos have moved to SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vdos/

You can download the latest version (with installer) there.

Comment: What is this? A direct download. No info page. No explanation to what this does and how it works (and would be preferred over the current method)? And would this solve printing over the network? Please clarify your answer or give an info-page. Just running a program downloaded from an unknown source is not advised.

Comment: As DOSbox, it emulates a DOS-PC, but is intended for “serious”, non-gaming, programs. It lacks most of the hardware emulation of DOSbox like non-vga graphics, joysticks, soundcards and the like. Instead it offers a live file system, file/record locking, printing and a scalable font/window. You can have a look at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIdtsvuDfr0, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCCFFIi60VQ, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYLQPjXHKsc.